# Кодировка DOCX файлов в Powershell

Tags: кодировка, powershell

Доброго времени! есть куча docx файлов, в которых ищется ФИО, переводится в переменную, а затем используется для переименования файла. так вот, поиск заканчивается неудачей т.к. powershell не понимает кодировку docx файлов. с txt-файлами в кодировки UTF-8 все отрабатывает замечательно

```
$pathtball = "C:\Users\Vasiliy\Desktop\BPM\treb\*"

$readfolders = Get-ChildItem $pathtball
foreach ($pathtbone in $readFolders)
{
    $index = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($pathtbone)

    # Индекс начала
    $IndexStart1 = $index.IndexOf("Уважаемый (ая) ")
    # Индекс конца
    $IndexEnd1 = $index.IndexOf("!")
    $indextotal1 = $index.Substring($IndexStart1, $IndexEnd1-$IndexStart1)
    $indextotal2 = $index.Substring($IndexStart2, $IndexEnd2-$IndexStart2)
}
```

Ошибка следующая

> Исключение при вызове "Substring" с "2" аргументами: "Значение
>   StartIndex не может быть меньше нуля. Имя параметра: startIndex"
>   C:\Users\Vasiliy\Desktop\BPM\renameallfilesv1.ps1:20 знак:36
>   +     $indextotal1 = $index.Substring <<<< ($IndexStart1, $IndexEnd1-$IndexStart1)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: Вероятно `docx` файлы не являются текстовыми. Откройте его в том же notepad, есть ли там искомая подстрока?

Comment: docx - это набор xml файлов и других ресурсов (изображений, например) внутри обычного zip архива (хотя и с расширением docx). Попробуйте любым архиватором открыть такой файл и посмотреть что внутри.

Comment: естественно когда открываю блокнотом, там набор символов, вот и мне и нужно перед обработкой изменить кодировку

Comment: docx файлы читают след. образом `(Select-OpenXmlString -path $file_name).content`

Comment: не находит командлет Select-OpenXmlString

Comment: @Василий установите http://powertools.codeplex.com/ чтобы найти командлет

Answer (score 1):

Файл **.docx** - документ, созданный с помощью Microsoft Word 2007 или более новой версии Office. **Формат** файла основан на **Open XML** и использует **сжатие** по алгоритму **ZIP** для уменьшения размера файла. Через обычный редактор он откроется, но понять, что там написано, вы не сможете. Исходя из выше изложенного изменение кодировки данного текста не поможет.

Чтобы прочесть файл docx в powershell, вам необходимо скачать и установить [Open-Xml-PowerTools](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools).

Использую команду:

```
(Select-OpenXmlString -path $file_name).content
```

Где переменная `$file_name` является файлом "*.docx", который требуется прочесть.

Спасибо [insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor), [Senior Pomidor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/209435/senior-pomidor), [1d0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188200/1d0) за оказанную помощь.